# Sorting issue with multiple series in a stacked bar char

Tags: sql-server, sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So my issue is fairly simple to explain but after trying every possible trick I know I am still stuck.  I have data I am running through a stacked chart and it has multiple series and multiple categories.  I am attempting to get all the data to sort in such away where in each series the top box = the first quartile, the second box = the second quartile, the third box = the third quartile and the final box at the bottom = the forth quartile.  Within each data set there can be both negative and positive values, so it makes sorting a little more tricky, but I have developed several methods in SQL to sort the data anyway I need.

Here is an image of the current issue:

Current Sorting 
[image]

It is suppose to obviously look different than this but it is kind of like playing whack a mole.

Here is a look at the raw data in question:

```
Category    Period  Value
1st quartile    YTD 8.11
1st quartile    1 Year  1.00
1st quartile    3 Year  4.39
1st quartile    5 Year  8.00
1st quartile    10 Year 2.78
2nd quartile    YTD 5.00
2nd quartile    1 Year  -2.35
2nd quartile    3 Year  -1.59
2nd quartile    5 Year  7.00
2nd quartile    10 Year 1.00
3rd quartile    YTD 2.00
3rd quartile    1 Year  -1.93
3rd quartile    3 Year  -1.64
3rd quartile    5 Year  5.00
3rd quartile    10 Year -1.00
4th quartile    YTD -7.00
4th quartile    1 Year  -6.93
4th quartile    3 Year  -5.09
4th quartile    5 Year  4.00
4th quartile    10 Year -2.11
```

So far I have tried the following:

1. Created a basic sort column via SQL to order the data in a specific fashion.  This works fine for almost all other chart types, Tablix, etc, but it fails on the stacked column type.
2. Considering the way that data is read into the stacked chart, I even created a very special custom sort that puts each data point into sequence based on how a stacked chart will fill out.  If all values are positive for example, for each data series:  The first data point will be the lowest and the last will the the highest.  I my use case, I need the first quartile at the top, so I put this in sort position 4, and I need the fourth quartile at the very bottom so I put this in sort position 1.  This works fine for a specific single series not for multiple series.  Just to be clear, I even built logic into the query to handle all the negative cases as well.  If there is a mix of positive and negative values, or if they are all positive or all negative, I have sort logic that works fine on just one series.  But if I run these together with multiple series the whole thing breaks and gets out of sequence.
3. I have tried putting sorting logic directly into SSRS in the series group.  I have tried single field sorts, IIF statements, IIF + And statements, Switch statements etc.  They all fail.

At this point I must be missing something.  Can anyone help?  I will be glad to provide any additional information needed to clarify any questions.

Here is a visual of the sort logic I am using:

[Sorting Logic Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9nki.png)

Here is an example of the SQL code I am using to achieve the sort logic in the photo.

```
      ,case when [YTD 4th Quartile] >=0 then 4
  when [YTD 3rd Quartile] >=0 and [YTD 4th Quartile] <0 then 3
  when [YTD 2nd Quartile] >=0 and [YTD 3rd Quartile] <0 then 2
  when [YTD 1st Quartile] >=0 and [YTD 2nd Quartile] <0 then 1
  when [YTD 1st Quartile] <0 then 2 
  else null end as [YTD Sort]

  ,case when [1 YR 4th Quartile] >=0 then 4
  when [1 YR 3rd Quartile] >=0 and [1 YR 4th Quartile] <0 then 3
  when [1 YR 2nd Quartile] >=0 and [1 YR 3rd Quartile] <0 then 2
  when [1 YR 1st Quartile] >=0 and [1 YR 2nd Quartile] <0 then 1
  when [1 YR 1st Quartile] <0 then 2 
  else null end as [1 YR Sort]

  ,case when [3 YR 4th Quartile] >=0 then 4
  when [3 YR 3rd Quartile] >=0 and [3 YR 4th Quartile] <0 then 3
  when [3 YR 2nd Quartile] >=0 and [3 YR 3rd Quartile] <0 then 2
  when [3 YR 1st Quartile] >=0 and [3 YR 2nd Quartile] <0 then 1
  when [3 YR 1st Quartile] <0 then 2 
  else null end as [3 YR Sort]

  ,case when [5 YR 4th Quartile] >=0 then 4
  when [5 YR 3rd Quartile] >=0 and [5 YR 4th Quartile] <0 then 3
  when [5 YR 2nd Quartile] >=0 and [5 YR 3rd Quartile] <0 then 2
  when [5 YR 1st Quartile] >=0 and [5 YR 2nd Quartile] <0 then 1
  when [5 YR 1st Quartile] <0 then 2 
  else null end as [5 YR Sort]

  ,case when [10 YR 4th Quartile] >=0 then 4
  when [10 YR 3rd Quartile] >=0 and [10 YR 4th Quartile] <0 then 3
  when [10 YR 2nd Quartile] >=0 and [10 YR 3rd Quartile] <0 then 2
  when [10 YR 1st Quartile] >=0 and [10 YR 2nd Quartile] <0 then 1
  when [10 YR 1st Quartile] <0 then 2 
  else null end as [10 YR Sort]
```

I already have this working on a single data series, the issue only comes up when I go to multiple series.

I greatly appreciate any insight on this issue.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: I'm not sure why you are sorting by the numeric values at all? Maybe I missed something. You say you always want Q1 at the top and Q4 at the bottom, so why not just sort by category and nothing else?

Comment: The reason I can't simply sort by numerical value (A-Z) or (Z to A) is due to the way that SSRS fills data into the stacked bar chart.  If the data was all 100% positive values this would be a no brainier but because some of the data is negative, simple (A-Z) sorting won

Comment: That's what I was saying. So you ARE sorting only by the category (the category name/label)?

Comment: The categories will not fill in the stacked bar properly in every scenario.  If all values are positive,or all the values are negative this would work fine.  But when there are a mix of positive and negative values the sort logic becomes more complex.  SSRS by default will sort all positive values by filling from the bottom up first, then it will fill the negative values from the top down.  I already built logic that will work on any single series in any given permutation but the issue is that when I run multiple series (YTD, 1YR, etc.) the sort logic falls apart and ignores my rules.

Comment: Can you normalize your values to 100% of a given range that always starts at zero. If you say sorting works when all values are >0 then the negative values can be converted to positive with smallest negative value being 0. If you can scheme your data around the point with the least value at 0% and the greatest value being 100%  then the you only have to fudge the axis values display logic using offsets.

Comment: Honestly it is not really the sorting logic that is the issue.  I have this figured out and it works for any single series fine.  The issue is that the sorting logic fails when I add multiple series.  I am starting to think that the SSRS can not handle any type of sorting logic with both positive and negative values across multiple series in a stacked bar chart.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: After trying a few different methods, the method provided by @RossBush seems to be the only option.  I now have the chart sorting, and working propertly, now I just need to change the axis to reflect the offset value.  I have captured this value in SQL and can access it via SSRS but I have not been able to successfully implement an axis offset with it yet.  Does anyone have any examples of using a value to offset the Y axis by say 20 or 30 integers?